# Implementing complex search in RESTfull service

Tags: api, rest, coldfusion

We are trying to implement a complex search functionality in Rest service using coldfusion 10. 
Something like projectid=1 and active=1 and (ManagerName contains John or ManagerName contains alfred)

One way of doing this is ?projectid=1&active=1&ManagerName=[John,Alfred]. However this does not serve my purpose as the ManagerName search will not return the required result. Also, as the number of search filter grows, the query string becomes tough to handle.

I tried to get an xml (with all search filter) as an input through HTTP Get Request, but that did not help, as GetHTTPRequestData() does not reflect the xml content.

Is there any means to pass an xml/json through an HTTP Get Request??
Will it be a bad practice, if xml is passed by a HTTP Post Request??
Are there any other options to pass complex filter param to a REST service??

i have gone through a lot of post on the site for similar question, but still could not find a solution to my problem.

Comment: Is the rest service written in ColdFusion?

Comment: @DanBracuk: Yes. The rest service is written in coldfusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GET` should be idempotent it should not modify the state of the Resource. strictly limit `get` usage to `Read` operations

your `POST` triggers Resource Creation i.e along with payload (xml/json).It is very bad practice to use POST for search.

Also you should take-care of the Cache-Control as your `GET` requests might get cached and if your search is real time you might get stale data.

You can take example as `stackoverflow` itself

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rest?sort=newest&pagesize=30

In above URl, path elements `questions` , `tagged`, `rest` derive subset of `question` resources.
The query parameters suggest filtering of those which met the creiteria.

Comment: And just to add to this - don't forget you can define arguments in your REST service and define them as coming from POST parameters.

Comment: @TechExchange: thanks for the inputs. My concern here is, if GET request is used to fetch data based on complex criteria, my URI would look clumsy and tough to manage for the consumer. Other way it can be done is by putting a limit to the search level and search options, right? is there any other way/standard to pass query string that is manageable.

Comment: @Kuhu you can push the boundaries of a specification if there is good reason. so you can send query as payload using GET

Comment: @TechExchange: I tried that option as well... however, the xml that i send through a get request is not available at the server (in my cf service). i tried to retrieve the xml using GetHTTPRequestData(), but no luck..

Comment: @Kuhu probably late response, but you can try POST->Redirect->GET. where as POST creates a Filter Resource and a Redirect request to GET the newly created Filter Resource.